# Arguments to macros in mathmode lose their mathmode typesetting

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros, arguments

I'm writing a little semantics package(I know that there already exists some good packages for this) in latex to help me and my friends out with our assignments.

but im having a broblem that arguments passed to macros lose mathmode formating even though the macro getts called from a mathmode enviroment and that the body of the macro has a `\ensuremath`.

Here is an example.

I have a macro defined as this:

```
\newcommand{\wAssign}[3]{
    \ensuremath{
        \operatorname{
        {#3}[{#1} \mapsto \mathcal{A}\llbracket {#2} \rrbracket {#3}] 
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this macro like so:

```
\subsection{Subtitle}
     \begin{equation}
     \wAssign{\mathtt{x}}{a+b}{s'}
\end{equation}
```

Wields the output:

[image: Bad output]

But what I'm after is this:

[image: Desired output]

Wich is what i get when using:

```
\begin{equation}
   s'[\mathtt{x} \mapsto \mathcal{A}\llbracket a+b \rrbracket s'] 
\end{equation}
```

It might not be super apparent but `'` is rendered completely differently and `a + b` are not in the correct font.

How does one fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the purpose of `\operatorname`? Just remove it.

Comment: Henrik: I'm somewhat curious as to why you chose to include `\operatorname` in the first place. What did you think it did? (honest question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\operatorname` is used for typesetting names of functions like sine, cosine and logarithm. In your macro it is exactly the part that does wrong, so remove it:

```
\newcommand{\wAssign}[3]{%
   {#3}[{#1} \mapsto \mathcal{A}\llbracket {#2} \rrbracket {#3}]%
}
```

I recommend *not* using `\ensuremath` and, in case, typing `$\wAssign{A}{B}{C}$` that's clearer, in my opinion, albeit requiring two keystrokes more.

If you really want to use `\ensuremath`, pay attention to spurious spaces:

```
\newcommand{\wAssign}[3]{%
   \ensuremath{%
     {#3}[{#1} \mapsto \mathcal{A}\llbracket {#2} \rrbracket {#3}]%
   }%
}
```

Actually just the first and fourth `%` are necessary, but the other two do no harm either.

Comment: Why are the `%` necessary?

Comment: that really solved it :)

I had troubles before to make arguments work at all in mathmode and some  other post on Tex.Sx said that the `\operatorname` was necessary.

Comment: @HenrikSommerland Spaces are ignored in math mode, but not in text mode; an end-of-line in a definition counts as a space in the replacement text, unless masked off with `%`.